# ¿Cómo puedo poner la variable a string vacío ("") después de devolverla?

Tags: c#, funciones, function, datagrid, datagridview

¿Cómo puedo poner la variable a string vacío ("") después de devolverla?
configurable_variations  tiene que volver a "" porque se va a invocar varias veces y tiene que restaurar su valor

````
        {
            string configurable_variations = "";
            
            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvrow in dataGridView2.Rows)
                {
                    configurable_variations += "sku=" + dgvrow.Cells["sku"].Value.ToString(); //sku

                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dgvrow.Cells["conector"].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        configurable_variations += ",conector=" + dgvrow.Cells["conector"].Value.ToString(); //P1
                    }

                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dgvrow.Cells["temperatura_color"].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        configurable_variations += ",temperatura_color=" + dgvrow.Cells["temperatura_color"].Value.ToString(); //temperatura_color
                    }

                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dgvrow.Cells["angulo"].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        configurable_variations += ",angulo=" + dgvrow.Cells["angulo"].Value.ToString(); //angulo
                    }

                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dgvrow.Cells["acabado"].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        configurable_variations += ",acabado=" + dgvrow.Cells["acabado"].Value.ToString(); //acabado
                    }

                    dgvrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Khaki;
                    configurable_variations += "|";

                }
                configurable_variations = configurable_variations.Remove(configurable_variations.Length - 1, 1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
           
            return configurable_variations;
            
        }```
````

Comment: Tu primera linea `string configurable_variations = "";` hace precisamente lo que necesitas. Si te refieres a establecerla a una cadena vacia despues del `return`, eso no será posible, pues todo código que se coloque alli, sera código inalcanzable, pues en esa linea, el procedimiento termina; pero cada ves que invoques el metodo tu primera linea `string configurable_variations = ""` la inicializa como una cadena vacia, me parece que eso es todo lo que necesitas.

Comment: Por qué usas esto `--- *** ` en la pregunta?